# CSS: Mega Menu - Absolute Height Issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ms6g9c61/1

As you can see, the main menu list goes only 2 lines deep. I need its height (visually you can see the blue border) adjust accordingly to the submenu thats open. Each submenu is not the same height.

Any idea of how to do this? I'm really trying not to use JS.

I was thinking maybe change the mark up so instead of lists, we can change it to be divs that work like tables? I don't know if that works because of the absolute positioning. 1 standard height won't work either, it has to be able to adjust with the diff. submenus.

Here is the HTML:

```css
body {
  margin: 15px;
}

.into {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.menuList {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menuList > li {
  background: white;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
}

.subMenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 161px;
  background: pink;
  width: 400px;
}

.submenuList {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menuList > li:hover > .subMenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="intro">
flyout menu w/ adjusting height<br/>
left menu must adjust in height to match submenu that appears to the right.
</p>

<ul class="menuList">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Category 1</a>
    <div class="subMenu">
      <ul class="submenuList">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Category 2</a>
    <div class="subMenu">
      <ul class="submenuList">
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want this? Is it just visual appeal to keep that border, or is there some functionality/UI that is broken due to the height? My suggestion would be to add the border to the submenu itself, and pull it to the left 1px so you don't see double border where the current one exists.

Comment: its just for visual appeal. the menu list will have a white background. as the submenu grows, it'll also have a white background. since the submenu would grow longer than the menu list, it would have 2 white blocks sitting on the site instead of looking like 1 all inclusive box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use position: relative for your elements. The upper MenuBox now resizes with the subitems.

I fiddled a bit for you:

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 15px;
}

.into {
  margin: 0;
}

.menuList {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menuList > li {
  background: white;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
}

.subMenu {
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 151px;
  background: pink;
  width: 400px;

}

.submenuList {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menuList > li:hover > .subMenu {
  display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.menuBox {
  position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="intro">
flyout menu w/ adjusting height<br/>
left menu must adjust in height to match submenu that appears to the right.
</p>

<div class="menuBox">
<ul class="menuList">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Category 1</a>
    <div class="subMenu">
      <ul class="submenuList">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Category 2</a>
    <div class="subMenu">
      <ul class="submenuList">
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```